# Most Efficient way to insert multiple rows of integers

Tags: t-sql

I have 2 simple select queries to get me a list of id's. My first table returns lets say 5 ids.
    1, 2, 5, 10, 23

My second table returns a list of 50 ids not in any order.

Whats is the most efficient way to write a query to map each of my ids from my first table to all the ids from the second table?

edit: sorry Here is more info.

If table 1 has a result of ids = 1, 2, 5, 10, 23
and table 2 has a list of ids = 123, 234, 345, 456, 567

I would like to write an insert that would insert into table 3 these values

```
 Table1ID | Table2ID
         1|123 
         1|234
         1|345
         1|456
         1|567
         2|123 
         2|234
         2|345
         2|456
         2|567
```

and so on.

Comment: I thnk we need more information, I have no idea what result you are hoping to get.

Answer (score 0):

Use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` statement with cross join:

```
INSERT INTO TableC (ID1, ID2)
SELECT A.ID AS ID1, b.ID AS ID2 FROM TableA A CROSS JOIN TableB B;
```

**[Sample DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ec589/1)**

`INSERT INTO…SELECT` is described on MSDN: [INSERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx)

> You can use `INSERT INTO <target_table> SELECT <columns> FROM
>   <source_table>` to efficiently transfer a large number of rows from one
>   table, such as a staging table, to another table with minimal logging.
>   Minimal logging can improve the performance of the statement and
>   reduce the possibility of the operation filling the available
>   transaction log space during the transaction.

Comment: Could you at least use ANSI syntax in your join?

Comment: @ErikE Why should I do that, when my code works just fine on SQL Server?

Comment: Because "works just fine" is a poor heuristic for choosing work practices, when [a host](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jamesw/archive/2011/10/03/a-list-of-sql-best-practices.aspx) of [sql professionals](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/496012) call it a [bad habit](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) and [recommend against it](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/brian_kelley/2009/09/30/the-old-inner-join-syntax-vs-the-new-inner-join-syntax/).

Comment: It is furthermore [deprecated by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172122.aspx).

Comment: I spend several hours a week digging through SQL code that was written 10 years ago in this form of syntax and I couldn't agree more with ErikE's comment.  Readability matters!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you are looking for is a Cartesian Product.

You can accomplish this simply by joining the two tables together with no join condition, which is accomplished by `CROSS JOIN`.

```
INSERT dbo.TableC (AID, BID)
SELECT A.ID, B.ID
FROM
   dbo.TableA A
   CROSS JOIN dbo.TableB B
;
```

Here is an image with a visualization of a Cartesian product. The inputs are small, just the column of symbols on the left corresponding to the first table, and the column on the right being the second table. Upon performing a `JOIN` with no conditions, you get one row per connecting line in the middle.

[image: Cartesian Product]